# Deferred Object: Restart after resolve

Tags: jquery, deferred

How can I set a Deffered from resolved back to the initial state?

I tried creating a new Queue, but in that case I will lose all events I have added so far, If I don't resolve it first.

Is there maybe a state model of the Deferred (Processing --> Resolved... maybe something in between, how you can get from Resolved into Processing....)

This is what I have so far:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Demo</title>
    <script src="jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        var deferredReady = jQuery.Deferred();

        $(function () {
            $('#Queue1, #Queue2').click(function () {
                var text = $(this).text();
                deferredReady.done(function () {
                    $('<p>', {
                        text: text
                    }).appendTo('body');
                });
            });
            $('#QueueReady').click(function () {
                deferredReady.resolve();
            });
            $('#NewQueue').click(function () {
                // deletes the old queue (resolve it first)
                deferredReady = jQuery.Deferred();
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <button id="Queue1">Add Comamnd to ready Queue</button>
    <button id="Queue2">Add  otherComamnd to ready Queue</button>
    <button id="QueueReady">Set Queue to ready</button>
    <button id="NewQueue">Set Queue to ready</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this conctraticts the original intent of deferred objects. As soon as a `Deferred` is resolved or rejected, previously specified callbacks are called and the Deferred changes *irrevocably* from its initial "pending" state to either "resolved" or "rejected". What would you expect from setting it back to the initial state? If you want to add a new handler to a deferred object which may or may not be already resolved, this is not a problem. The handler will be called immediately:

```
$.Deferred().resolve().then(function() { alert('This works!'); });
```

Comment: Agreed but the sentence "As soon as a Deferred is resolved, the associated handlers are called and the deferred object is "done", it has no further purpose" needs some work. How about "As soon as a Deferred is resolved or rejected, previously specified callbacks are called and the Deferred changes *irrevocably* from its initial "pending" state to either "resolved" or "rejected".

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, I changed the wording.